# positioning of all div elements from top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div tag `<div class="parent">` in which I load all my questions at once when my page loads and hide it. Questions are label specific when a **user** clicks on that label, those label specific questions show on the screen

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="labelsBRAND" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsSTYLING" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style=""></div>
<div class="labelsSTYLING" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Initially, all its display is none

```
.labelsWARDROBE {
 display: none;
}
.labelsSTYLING{
  display: none;
}
.labelsBRAND{
  display: none;
}
```

and I display those questions whose label was clicked, the problem is that questions are shown in very random on the screen some shown from the top and others from the middle and others from below middle and my screen height also gets an increase which makes it clumsy, it's not fixed, how to use `CSS` to position all the question on the from the top.
I tried the class of parent div also but again for positions of displaying of questions labelsBRAND is different as from labelsWARDROBE

```
.parent{
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
}
```

I used this `CSS` for labels

```
.labelsWARDROBE {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  display: none;
}
.labelsSTYLING{
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  display: none;
}
.labelsBRAND{
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  display: none;
}
```

But this I used on the basis of my judgement by looking the position of questions, it's not dynamic, how to make it dynamic and whenever the label is clicked the questions should start displaying from the top

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: If that so all of your DOM elements are Div so you can try `div{position:relative}`

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just remove `top: -...px` from your css. Top / left / bottom & right are used for absolute positioning. In your case you wont need that. Css & html are smart enough to always start from the top if you have all your elements positioned relative. So your css should be like this:

```
.labelsWARDROBE {
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
.labelsSTYLING{
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
.labelsBRAND{
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
```

I also made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/d8m4L2nL/1/

In this fiddle all options are positioned relative & visible. You can simply set some classes `display: none` to see the effect.

Comment: I see its working on fiddle but in my case, its not working ,maybe because of other different CSS which is happening that page

Comment: Yes probably because of that. You can use the browser inspector tool (in chrome it's the f12 key) to see if there are any styles added to your class from elsewhere

Comment: i inspected the browser and changed this css in styles tab
.labelsSTYLING {
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    display: none;
}, then it moves to the top, but its wrong why not its moves from postion: relatives

Comment: it's really hard for me to find out what's wrong as I have no Idea what your other css is like. All I know is that my code works in theory, as long as there is no other style overwriting what I just posted.

Comment: i am using jquery hide and show(), i think thats causing the bug, how to use show() to make it display from the top

Comment: you can try this: $(".YOURCLASSNAME").css("display","block"); This will literally set your css from none to block

Answer (score 0):

If that so all of your DOM elements are Div so you can try `div{position:relative}`. There is no need to make it more complicated

```css
div {
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="labelsBRAND" style="">efefef</div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style="">efefefe</div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style="">efefefe</div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style="">efefefe</div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style="">efefef</div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style="">efefef</div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style="">efefefe</div>
<div class="labelsWARDROBE" style="">fefefe</div>
<div class="labelsSTYLING" style="">efefef</div>
<div class="labelsBRAND" style="">efefef</div>
<div class="labelsSTYLING" style="">feeffe</div>
</div>
```